# C echo server still echoes once after being terminated

Tags: c, tcp, echo, server

I have written a simple echo server and a client in C.

Here is the server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "unp.h"

#define SERVER_PORT 10000

void start_echo_service(int connfd);
void SIGCHLD_handler(int signum);

int main()
{
    int listenfd, connfd;
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;

    pid_t child_pid;

    printf("***Starting the echo server***\n");

    if((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to create connection socket. Exiting...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    bzero(&client_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    if(bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    {
        strerror(errno);
        exit(0);
    }

    if(listen(listenfd, 1000) < 0)
    {
        strerror(errno);
        exit(0);
    }

    /* Add the handler for SIGCHLD */
    struct sigaction sigchld_action;
    sigchld_action.sa_handler = SIGCHLD_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sigchld_action.sa_mask);
    sigchld_action.sa_flags = 0;
    if(sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sigchld_action, NULL) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error while adding handler for SIGCHLD\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        len = sizeof(client_addr);
        if((connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &len)) < 0)
        {
            if(errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            else
            {
                strerror(errno);
                exit(0);
            }
        }

        child_pid = fork();
        if(child_pid < 0)
        {
            //some error occured
            strerror(errno);
            exit(0);
        }
        else if(child_pid == 0)
        {
            // child process
            close(listenfd);
            start_echo_service(connfd);
            close(connfd);
            exit(1);
        }

        close(connfd);
    }
    close(connfd);

    return 1;
}

void SIGCHLD_handler(int signum)
{
    pid_t pid;
    if((pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) > 0)
        printf("Harvested child (pid): %d\n", pid);
}

void start_echo_service(int connfd)
{
    char buf[256];
    int bytes_read;

    while(1)
    {
        if((bytes_read = read(connfd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
        {
            writen(connfd, buf, bytes_read);
            continue;
        }
        else if(bytes_read == 0)
            break;
        else
        {
            if(errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            else
            {
                printf("Read error\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "unp.h"

#define SERVER_PORT 10000

void start_echo_client(int connfd);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int connfd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: echo_client <server-address>\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &(server_addr.sin_addr));
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    if((connfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        strerror(errno);
        exit(0);
    }

    if(connect(connfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    {
        strerror(errno);
        exit(0);
    }

    start_echo_client(connfd);

    return 1;
}

void start_echo_client(int connfd)
{
    char buffer[256];

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        writen(connfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        readn(connfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
}
```

I start my server with `./echo_server` on one shell.
I start my client with `./echo_client 127.0.0.1` on another shell. So far, so good.

On my client, I type a message, say `hello`. The server echoes it back. Now, I terminate my server with `Ctrl+C`. The client is still running. Now, I type another message on the client, say `zzz`. I still get an echo back and `zzz` is printed on the shell. On typing another message on the client, it terminates.

I guess it may have something to do with the server being in uninterruptible sleep when I terminate it, but I can't be sure.

Here is the link to [unp.h](https://gist.github.com/kunalsinha/c1fc7349e9ef377d3add) and [unp.c](https://gist.github.com/kunalsinha/35514b04db1e41f2a2e2)

Comment: So your server didn't terminate. No other explanation makes sense.

Comment: Did you make sure the server actually terminated?

Comment: Check [EINTR and What It Is Good For](http://250bpm.com/blog:12) Also, why return 1? Isn't that the normal path of termination for which your return one?

Comment: Atleast from the wireshark dump, I see the last one after ctrl-c does not reach server and there is no echo. Rather there is RST for the last one that is sent from server.

Comment: You `^C`'ed your server while it's waiting inside a syscall, and you happen to retry upon this situation.

Comment: @EJP @FUZxxl Checked using both `ps` and `netstat`. The server entry didn't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start_echo_client` prints `buffer` irrespective of the return from `readn`, isn't? Even if server closed, buffer would contain contents of what happened with `writen` ( You use same buffer for write and read). Hence i think, you assume there was an echo from server while it was not.

The test with tcpdump as well indicates that FIN does arrive with ctrl-c on the server terminal. Client tries `write` ignoring the peer closure for which RST is received.

Also, `read` didn't yield zero on FIN. I changed to `recv` then the closure was caught.

Return the number of bytes read in the `readn` function instead what is being currently done and if its zero, then don't print buffer.

Comment: You are right. The `read` did return zero, after I shut down the server. However, I printed the same buffer, which led me to assume I got an echo. On the next `write`, the client code got a `SIGPIPE` and terminated. Turns out the mistake was silly after all. Thanks :D